# I am having issues serving a web page with python

Tags: python, web-services

I am trying to serve a basic webpage in python.
If I cd to the dir and then run "python -m http.server 80" The page is displayed without issues, all formatting is correct. The issue is that I require some degree of security, so I have written a basic authentication python script which i run from the same directory. Unfortunately I get a badly rendered page with no formatting. Can anybody help me? All i need do is once fully authenticated, launch this web site in current directory.

Code is :-

```
import http.server
import socketserver
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class CustomHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    ''' Main class to present webpages and authentication. '''
    def do_HEAD(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        print ('all authenticated')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_AUTHHEAD(self):
        self.send_response(401)
        self.send_header('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm=\"SmarterADM\"')
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        ''' Present frontpage with user authentication. '''
        if self.headers['Authorization'] == None:
            self.do_AUTHHEAD()
            self.wfile.write(bytes('no auth header received', 'UTF-8'))
            pass
        elif self.headers['Authorization'] == 'Basic c21hcnRlcmFkbTpwYXNzdzByZA==':
             self.do_HEAD()
             self.wfile.write(bytes(self.headers['Authorization'], 'UTF-8'))
             self.wfile.write(bytes(' authenticated!', 'UTF-8'))
             rootdir = 'c:/Team/main/START/index.html' #file location
             f = open(rootdir,'rb') #open requested file
             self.wfile.write(f.read())
             return render.rootdir
             pass
        else:
             self.do_AUTHHEAD()
             self.wfile.write(bytes(self.headers['Authorization'], 'UTF-8'))
             self.wfile.write(bytes(' not authenticated Mark says NO!', 'UTF-8'))
             pass

httpd = HTTPServer(('', 80), CustomHandler)
print ('started httpd...')
httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
''''         rootdir = 'c:/RTS_Team/STAR2/STAR2/index.html' #file location
        f = open(rootdir,'rb') #open requested file
        self.wfile.write(f.read())
        f.close() '''
```

Comment: At this point you really should consider using a proper web framework.

Comment: you should look at django

Comment: Since you seem to want something minimal, [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) and a simple authentication library [bottle-cork](https://github.com/FedericoCeratto/bottle-cork) should do the trick.